# How class binding actually works under the hood in angular because there is no such dom property known as class?

Tags: javascript, angular

```
<div [class]="className">Special</div>
```

since class isn't a property of a dom element how come class is used here as a property name ?

Comment: refer this https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-context

Comment: i have seen over there they are calling it as class binding ..this is not the answer of my question